# Why does Systemd_Wants not pass a parameter to a service file from a udev "Remove" rule?

Tags: usb, systemd, mount, udev

I am trying to use udev rules and systemd to mount and unmount a USB key.

I am basing my solution below on an example from [this blog](http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/01/12/starting-systemd-service-instance-for-device-from-udev.html) where ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS} is used in an "Add" udev rule. I could not get ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS} to work for a "Remove" rule so I ended up using the example in [this blog entry](https://andreafortuna.org/2019/06/26/automount-usb-devices-on-linux-using-udev-and-systemd/) which runs a systemd service file from a udev RUN key.

Although this solution works the [udev man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html) says: "Running an event process for a long period of time may block all further events for this or a dependent device."

These are the rules I use...

**The Add Rule:**

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_TYPE}="disk", \ 
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ENV_MOUNT_USB}="MOUNT", \ 
PROGRAM="/usr/bin/systemd-escape -p --template=usb-mount@.service \ 
$env{DEVNAME}", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="%c"
```

**The Remove Rule:**

```
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_TYPE}="disk", \ 
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start usb-umount@%k.service"
```

These are the systemd service files that the udev rules start. They simply execute bash scripts to mount and un-mount the USB key.

**usb-mount@.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount USB Drive on %i
BindTo=%i.device
After=%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=300
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/usb-mount.sh /%I
```

**usb-umount@.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=UnMount USB Drive on %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=300
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/usb-umount.sh /%I
```

**My Problem**
But if I use ENV{SYSTEM_WANTS} in the "remove" rule the device block (e.g: /dev/sdb1) of the detaching USB key does NOT get passed to the service file. Actually I don't think the service file runs at all.

**My Question**
Can my remove rule be changed to work with ENV{SYSTEM_WANTS} and NOT RUN+={..} such that the /dev/sdb1 is passed to the service file and on to a script that can do the un-mount?

Cheers,

Flex

Answer (score 5):

After much investigation I have an answer to my question above.

### Explanation of Problem

The key points are in the [Systemd device man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.device.5.html):

> • (In a udev rule) "Systemd_wants="... "Adds dependencies of type
> Wants= from the device unit (e.g: a USB Key) to the specified units
> (i.e: a systemd service unit)."
>
> •  “...systemd will only act on Wants= dependencies when a device
> first becomes active.”

I tested by inserting and removing a USB key. From testing this udev rule does not work:

```
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_TYPE}="disk", \
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="usb-umount@%k.service"
```

I debugged like this:

```
sudo udevadm control --log-priority=debug
journalctl -f
```

When I removed the already inserted USB key I didn't see any mention of the usb-mount service in the `journalctl` debug output. So that service file doesn't even start which makes sense because of what the man page states (see above).

In contrast when I change the rule to this:

```
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_TYPE}="disk", \
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start usb-umount@%k.service"
```

Now in the `journalctl` output I see:

```
sdb1: Starting '/bin/systemctl start usb-umount@sdb1.service'
```

There is a good discussion about why Systemd_Wants will not work in a udev remove rule in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/systemd/comments/omdxq6/udev_rules_and_envsystemd_user_wants/).

To quote from that Reddit Thread:

> “SYSTEMD_WANTS and SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS do not make sense with
> ACTION=="remove". It may look like these variables make Udev ask
> systemd to do something, but the relationship is actually the other
> way around: the variable is retrieved from Udev by systemd when the
> device unit is being added to the systemd manager. The variable is not
> retrieved at any other time.”

This also explains why Systemd_Wants does not make the usb-mount service run from a udev "remove" rule.

### A New solution

That Reddit Thread also shows a roundabout way to use systemd_wants with a udev “remove” action:

Now to use udev to respond to a USB key being plugged and unplugged from my machine I need just ONE udev rule, inspired by the Reddit post and [this blog](http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/01/12/starting-systemd-service-instance-for-device-from-udev.html):

**The udev rule**
• /etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_TYPE}="disk", \
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ENV_MOUNT_USB}="USB-MOUNTED", \
PROGRAM="/usr/bin/systemd-escape -p --template=test-mount@.service \ 
$env{DEVNAME}", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="%c"
```

**The Service file**
• /etc/systemd/system/test-mount@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test-Mount USB Drive on %i
BindsTo=%i.device
After=%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStartSec=300
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/test-mount.sh /%I
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/test-umount.sh /%I
```

**The scripts I used...**
• /usr/local/sbin/test-mount.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# This script runs when a USB device is plugged in
#

DEVBASE=$1
DEVICE="${DEVBASE}"

# Create a Timestamp, e.g: 06.05.2022-20.11.49
current_time=$(date "+%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M.%S")

# Query the udev database which is available while the USB key is plugged in.
# However these udev properties are unavailable once the USB key is plugged out.
eval $(udevadm info --query=env --export $DEVICE)

# Create a temporary file
touch /tmp/test-mount.txt

# Add content to the file
echo ${current_time} > "/tmp/test-mount.txt"
echo ${DEVICE} >> "/tmp/test-mount.txt"
echo $ID_FS_LABEL  >> "/tmp/test-mount.txt"
echo $ENV_MOUNT_USB  >> "/tmp/test-mount.txt"
```

• /usr/local/sbin/test-umount.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# This script runs when a USB device is plugged out
#

DEVBASE=$1
DEVICE="${DEVBASE}"

# Create a Timestamp, e.g: 06.05.2022-20.11.49
current_time=$(date "+%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M.%S")

# Query the udev database which is available while the USB key is plugged in.
# However these udev properties are unavailable once the USB key is plugged out.
eval $(udevadm info --query=env --export $DEVICE)

# Create a temporary file
touch /tmp/test-umount.txt

# Add content to the file
echo ${current_time} > "/tmp/test-umount.txt"
echo ${DEVICE} >> "/tmp/test-umount.txt"
echo $ID_FS_LABEL  >> "/tmp/test-umount.txt"
echo $ENV_MOUNT_USB  >> "/tmp/test-umount.txt"
/usr/bin/printenv > /tmp/udev-env.txt
```

**The commands I used to Test and Debug**
• Insert USB and Remove USB key:

```
ls -l /tmp
```

**Debug like this...**
• This is really the only way you should bother testing a udev rule!
• Run the commands then insert and remove the USB key.

```
sudo udevadm control --log-priority=debug
journalctl -f
```

And also this...

```
udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=block --property --udev
udevadm monitor --property --udev
```

**Test like this...**
• This tests is not as useful as the above, as it only simulates what the udev rule *would* do!
• E.g: For /dev/sdb1 you test the udev rule like this:

```
# sudo udevadm test --action=add /sys/class/block/sdb1
```